# Prove existence of $n$ for an infinite product

Tags: real-analysis

I've been studying a paper in which the author says:

Fix $n$ such that $m^n \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{j+\delta} > 1$, where $1<m<\infty$, and $\delta >0$.

I seem not to be able to show why such $n$ must exist. I tried rewriting it this way:

$m^n \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{j+\delta} =m^n \prod_{j=1}^n (1-\frac{\delta}{j+\delta})= m^n \exp\bigg[\sum_{j=1}^n \log(1-\frac{\delta}{j+\delta})\bigg] \geq m^n\bigg[1+\sum_{j=1}^n \log(1-\frac{\delta}{j+\delta})\bigg]$

but after that I'm stuck. In one part the author writes

$m^n \prod_{j=1}^n (1-\frac{\delta}{j+\delta}) \geq m^n e^{c_0} \exp\bigg[-\delta\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j+\delta}\bigg]$, where $c_0$ is some constant,

but then I still don't know how this guarantees that there exists $n$ such that $m^n \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{j+\delta} > 1$. Does anyone have any idea on how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this, or at least I managed to convince myself that this is true. Approximately, we have that

$\prod_{j=1}^{n} \frac{j}{j+\delta} = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{\delta}{j+\delta}\right) \geq c_0 \exp\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n} \log\left(1 - \frac{\delta}{j+\delta}\right) \right] \geq c_0 \exp\left[-\delta\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{j+\delta} \right] \geq \frac{c_0}{n^{\delta}},$

where $c_0$ is a constant and since $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{j+\delta} \sim \log(n)$.

Therefore, we have that $m^n \prod_{j=1}^{n} \frac{j}{j+\delta} \geq \frac{m^n}{n^{\delta}}$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{m^n}{n^{\delta}} = \infty$ since $m>1$ and $\delta>0$.

In particular, as $\frac{m^n}{n^{\delta}}$ is also an increasing function in $n$, there exists $n_0>0$ such that $\frac{m^n}{n^{\delta}}>1$.

Answer (score -1):

Find an $N$ such that $\frac{mN}{N+\delta}>1+\eta$ for some $\eta>0$. Then take $M$ such that $(1+\eta)^M>\left(\prod_{j=1}^N\frac{j}{j+\delta}\right)^{-1}$. Then take $n=N+M$.

Comment: So you reduced "take $n$" to "take $M$", without any justification worth mentioning.

Comment: @ProfessorVector the existence of $N$ follows since $n/(n+\delta)\uparrow1$ as $n\to\infty$, and since $m>1$. Then for $n=N+1,\ldots,M$ each factor is larger then $1+\eta$; then the factors $N+1$ up to $M$ are larger than $(1+\eta)^M$, which is in turn larger than the product of the first $N$ factors $\prod_{j=1}^Nj/(j+\delta)$, if we take $M$ sufficiently large.

Comment: In the above comment I meant in the second sentence: the product of the factors $N+1$ up to $N+M$ are larger than $(1+\eta)^M$